# Помогите определиться с клиентским языком программирования?

Tags: javascript, android, linux, веб-программирование

Хочу написать динамическую браузерную 2D игру, но не могу определиться, на каком языке программирования писать клиентскую часть. Хотелось, чтобы клиентская часть была кроссплатформменная (в браузере, телефоне, ПК).

1. JavaScript - говорят, что будет тормозить при большом количестве анимации и графики, безопасность хромает...
2. Flash - проблема в том, что у меня Linux.
3. Java - я его боюсь. Очень много зависимости от ПО клиента (например: Java - апплет), и очень много разновидностей Java (Java EE, Java FX, Java SE...) и ее документации, непонятно, какую библиотеку изучать для решения такой "задачи".

Есть еще какой-нибудь язык, который покрывает все платформы, например, такой же, как JavaScript или Flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Динамическую, браузерную, кроссплатформенную" - остается не так уж и много комбинаций различных технологий, которые можно использовать. Осталось лишь добавить: "Выберите только два из трех". )

На самом деле Javascript будет самым подходящим решением. Не чистый JS, конечно же, а заключенный в рамки какого-нибудь фреймворка вроде PhoneGap. Это откроет вам практически безграничные возможности к технологиям HTML5+CSS3 со всеми, как вы догадываетесь, их плюшками. Действительно, кроссплатформенно, динамично (смотря что вы имеете в виду здесь) и работать будет внутри браузера.

Flash - умирающая технология, и, раз вы с ней не знакомы, то знакомится теперь уже не перспективно. Тут, думаю, уместно сказать: "Выбросите из головы."

Java... какие тут "зависимости"... такие же, как и компьютер зависит от шнура и розетки? JVM и JRE в большинстве случаев стоят по умолчанию (штатно ), т.к. без них множество прикладных программных компонентов не смогут работать. С другой стороны, с кроссплатформенностью тут будет несколько потуже: вы заикнулись про апплеты, а некоторые реализации того же Chromium по умолчанию блокируют их, т.к. на данный момент далеко не все уязвимости запатчены, а потому есть риск потенциальной угрозы.

**Вердикт: не стесняйтесь JavaScript`а, особенно заключенного внутрь фреймворка PhoneGap**.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал @0x0001 не заниматься некромантией и отринуть идею использования апплетов в первую очередь.

Comment: Flash уже лет пять хоронят, с тех пор как появилось открытое письмо Джобса, но все никак не похоронят. И видимо, его еще долго будут хоронить. 



У HTML+CSS как раз таки нету плюшек для высокодинамического контента, в том-то вся и беда. Ему на смену должен был придти канвас, но что-то пошло не так. У Canvas есть только [50 самых низкоуровневых функций](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/), на которых программировать просто "незабываемо"(в плохом смысле). Какие он дает преимущества на практике, а не на словах, мне не понятно, одни мучения. Тем более профессиональных инструментов так и нету, увы((

Comment: А вот у Flash как раз таки есть куча преимуществ, причем одним из них является возможность экспорта в SVG, WebGL и как ни странно конвертация в тот же JavaScript.

[линк раз](https://www.adobe.com/ru/products/flash/features.html)

[линк два](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/how-to/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html?set=flash--whats-new--2013-12)

Comment: Вердикт: не стесняйтесь Flash`а, особенно, заключенного внутрь AIR. 
То что у Вас, @0x0001 Linux не мешает писать код на AS3 (что на много удобнее JS), сам 3 года сидел на Flex под Linux полет нормальный.  
И как вариант можете Unity заюзать тоже уже у всех стоит, тоже крос платформенно, а если у Вас игра то вообще ни че не парит.

Comment: Тот приятный момент, когда двоичную систему учит шестнадцатеричная....

Answer (score 0):

> Есть еще какой нибудь язык который покрывает все платформы например такой же как JavaScript или Flash?

Вроде как есть еще Lazarus. Хотя я бы java взял.